# Create custom blur UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I have to develop an app that uses a a blur view.

I've tried to use `UIVisualEffectView` with `UIBlueEffect` but then I realised that there are just 3 types of blur that you can choose from, without an option to customise the blur.

I need to make a blur that is something between the `Light` and `Dark` modes, but I don't know how can I create a custom blur view.

Any idea on how can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

User below code for the blur effect

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Also you can use below library

https://github.com/ide/UIVisualEffects